# facebook comments API - what does facebook mean by "behind the comments box"?

Tags: javascript, python, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am reading the comments API of facebook from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/ and dont understand what they mean by this:

```
Simply grab the comments from the API and 
render them in the body of your page behind the comments box
```

I know how to grap but how do i render them `behind the comments box`? comment box is an iframe and i cannot plug any content into it, right? what do they mean by **`behind the comments box`**?

for any guidance, i would be thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is layered according to the order of the elements in the code.

You can also  control this with `z-index` and `position` properties from CSS.

I suppose they mean you should render this with a lower z-index then the comment box containing element.

Comment: so, it means that i will make the grabbed text not visible to user, right?

Comment: Seems like it, You can inspect the source code of other websites using this part of the API.

Comment: isnot it then bad, because i am hiding some text from user but showing to search engine?